# How to remove left and right padding for a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Left and Right padding is added automatically. This is the code I used. I'm running the app on Android version 6.0.1.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="45dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

Comment: please check for padding tags in parent layout. Sometimes Android Activities have some padding tags on root (Parent) layout.

Comment: Parent Layout doesn't have any padding

Answer (score 8):

Use as the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="45dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"               //Add this
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"               //Add this
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation= "0dp"  //Add this too
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

Comment: Edited the answer, please try this

Answer (score 2):

I added the below line of code and it worked.

```
 android:padding="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting contentInsetStartWithNavigation to 0dp as well. Like contentInsetStart, contentInsetStartWithNavigation also is 16dp by default. Try this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="45dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

Also, trying replacing the 'app' with 'android' if you haven't already. Sometimes we try to fix compatibility issues when there are none. Try this:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="45dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
```

You can also hard-code your Toolbar attributes in your activity file. You will use padding if you do so.

```
     Toolbar tb = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     tb.setPadding(padding, tb.getPaddingTop(), padding, tb.getPaddingBottom());
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you found a solution. Turned out to be the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

check the parent element and if you include the toolbar check to parent too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve the problem is to create a custom toolbar:

First create a custom toolb:

```
class CustomToolbar(context: Context): androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar(context) {

    constructor(context: Context , attrs: AttributeSet): this(context)
    constructor(context: Context , attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): this(context)

    override fun getContentInsetStart(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getContentInsetEnd(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getContentInsetLeft(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getContentInsetRight(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCurrentContentInsetStart(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCurrentContentInsetEnd(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCurrentContentInsetLeft(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCurrentContentInsetRight(): Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere without any problems:

```
<com.example.CustomToolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">
  //your views or layouts
</com.example.CustomToolbar>
```

Note that com.example is my package name and you must replace your project package name.